# Call and execute multiple child functions on parent button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, parent

I am trying to call each child components functions from parent component button click.Try to do it using props and assigning button click to new function on  componentDidMount function, but the result is that only the last function *alert("child2 save");* is being assigned and executed on button click, I expected that *alert("child1 save");* will also be executed.

How to do that each child function to be called on parent component button click, note that child components have quite big nested level inside of parent component.

```
 class Parent extends Component {

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={onSaveClick}>Save</button>
            <MainSection setSave={save=> this.onSaveClick= save}>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }


  class MainSection extends Component {
      render() {
        const {setSave} = this.props;
        return (
          <div>
              <Section1 setSave={setSave}>
              <Section2 setSave={setSave}>
          </div>
        );
      }
  }



  class Section1 extends Component {
      render() {
        const {setSave} = this.props;
        return (
          <div>
              <Child1 setSave={setSave}>
          </div>
        );
      }
  }



 class Section2 extends Component {
      render() {
        const {setSave} = this.props;
        return (
          <div>
              <Child2 setSave={setSave}>
          </div>
        );
      }
  }



  class Child1 extends Component {
      onSave() {
           alert("child1 save");
      } 
      componentDidMount() {
          const {setSave} = this.props;
          setSave(this.onSave);
      }
      render() {
        return (<div>Child1</div>);
      }
  }



  class Child2 extends Component {
      onSave() {
          alert("child2 save");
      } 

      componentDidMount() {
          const {setSave} = this.props;
          setSave(this.onSave);
      }

      render() {
        return (<div>Child2</div>);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.child = React.createRef();
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.child.current.getAlert();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child ref={this.child} />
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  getAlert() {
    alert('getAlert from Child');
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You could do it like this and have different ref for all the childs. Or you can have a state variable in parent and pass it down to childs from parent, and have an eventHandler in componentDidUpdate in the child components. And change the state whenever you want to trigger the child functions.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
if(prevProps.parentVariable !== this.props.parentVariable) {
  console.log("parent called");
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer 
Yes this is good solution, but in my real case I have not only 2  but many child components 20 or more  which are being rendered dynamically and there is no direct connection between parent and child they have 6 or more level of nested components in parent component until reach to child component level itself, what can I do in that case how should I pass this references to child components?

Comment: you can use redux and wrap all your components, and dispatch action, and compare prevProps value to current value in the nested components.